# Electron notifications don't bring app up to front again on click on the notification

Tags: notifications, electron

I have an electron app that will just wrap a remote page while adding some extra features. With the following code the page loads and works. When the remote page fires some notifications using the notification API those notifications show up when the electron app is minimized. My problem is that when clicking on those notifications the app does not get put to front like it does when opening the remote page on any other browser directly. I could test this only for Ubuntu 19.10 Linux (Gnome 3).

**Any idea if I need to configure something for that or if this is a bug with Electron/Ubuntu/Gnome?**

```
const {app, shell, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 786,
  });

  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.setTitle('My app – Connecting…');
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://some.url.somwhere');


  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

First of it is NOT a good idea to wrap a remote page unless you really know what you are doing as if you were redirected to a malicious page the page would have access to run code in the operating system. I would suggest giving [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) a read to make sure you're being safe.

Secondly the notification HTML5 API (runs in renderer) and notification module (runs in main) both do not have default behaviour to bring the page to the front when the notification is clicked you must add this behaviour yourself.

Because your loading a remote page you're probably using the notification module therefore it would be accomplished like follows:

```
notification = new Notification({title: "Message from: "+result[i].messageFrom,body: messagebody,icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets','images','icon.png')})
notification.show()


notification.on('click', (event, arg)=>{
    mainWindow.moveTop()
    mainWindow.focus()
})
```

Comment: What if the notification variable is in the remote application code?